# Call os.system(command) without popup

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I use a system call (mklink) to create a hard link in Windows. It works great, but it flashes a command window for a split second.

How can I avoid this command window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the module `subprocess`

```py
import subprocess

mycommand = "mklink"

subprocess.call(mycommand, shell=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write `mklink`

Comment: By default with `shell=True`, `Popen` instructs cmd.exe to hide the console window. This suffices when we actually need the shell such as for its internal `mklink` command. If we don't need the shell, a better way is to instruct the child process to not even create a console window, which we do via the argument `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (i.e. 0x08000000).